# Why does my computer say that there is an 11.10 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I always use `update-manager -d` just so I remember that there is a space bar between manager and -d.  I ran it today and it showed the bellow image.

[image]

Why does it do this or is there really an 11.10 update?  Is someone just screwing around with me?

Comment: The one who taught you to use `-d` flag is screwing around with you. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-d` means development release, and that would be Oneiric. Just run it without the flag, and you will get regular updates.

---

```
egil@morgenstern [~] $ update-manager --help
Usage: update-manager [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -V, --version         Show version and exit
  --data-dir=DATA_DIR   Directory that contains the data files
  -c, --check-dist-upgrades
                        Check if a new Ubuntu release is available
  -d, --devel-release   Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is
                        possible
  -p, --proposed        Upgrade using the latest proposed version of the
                        release upgrader
  --no-focus-on-map     Do not focus on map when starting
  --dist-upgrade        Try to run a dist-upgrade
  --no-update           Do not check for updates when starting
  -s, --sandbox         Test upgrade with a sandbox aufs overlay
```

Comment: Okay, so they haven't actually released it.  It is just a really early developer release for 11.10.

Comment: Yes. Alpha1 is two days away on june 2.